# How to remove the collapse in a table using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a status cars for a character using Css and Html and I ant to remove those black collapse from the inside of the table so that it ill look like it's 40% Red and 60% Green.
Like the photo here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKVUm.png)

I tried this:

```
.border table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 235px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.border td{    
    padding:3px; /* the height */
    border:2px solid black;
}
.percent20{
    background-color:#ff000d;
}
.percent60{
    background-color:rgba(18, 148, 18, 0.7);
}
```

But it didn't work and that's the further point I've reached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jkps.png)

The HTML code:

```
<div class="border">
     <table>
          <tr>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent20"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
          <tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I tried using just divs without using any tables but I cant make the percentages and all I got is small squares.

Comment: Remove `border:2px solid black`, and set `border-right` to `percent20`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself, Making the table with Html is just pain so I created it with only Divs.
The Css code:

```
/* Making table with only divs */
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    column-count: 5;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.class1, .class2{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    column-span: 2;
}
.class1 {
   columns: 2;
   background-color:#ff000d;
}
.class2 {
    columns: 3;
    background-color: rgba(18, 148, 18, 0.7);
}
```

The Html code:

```
<div class="border">
     <div class="divTable" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
          <div class="divTableBody">
               <div class="divTableRow">
                     <div class="class1"></div>
                     <div class="class2"></div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ***colspan*** for this particular scenario as it will combine multiple columns into one and you will be left with two columns which you can turn red or green as per your requirement.

Comment: Adding **colspan** doesn't solve the problem, To solve it with **colspan** I need to make another column in the table and that's not what I want to do. I just need to  remove the collapse from the inside You can try your idea your self I tried it but nothing changed unless adding another column to the table.

Comment: another workaround can be if you use a border of 2px or anything like that on the table itself but not on <td> elements instead you can use an extra class maybe name it as mark and provide it a right border of 2px. now you can use this class on td element of your choice

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{
        border-collapse: collapse; /* Remove cell spacing */
        width: 235px;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    table, th, td{
       padding:3px; /* the height */
       border:2px solid black;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px; /* Apply cell padding */
    }
    
    .percent20{
        background-color:#ff000d;
     }
    .percent60{
         background-color:rgba(18, 148, 18, 0.7);
     }
```

```html
<div class="border">
     <table>
          <tr>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent20"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
               <td class="percent60"></td>
          <tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not solving my problem, u just switched the td in the tables and applied cell padding. There's a photo represent the final product i anna make